# R Shiny DT datatable filtering multiple choices

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In a shiny App where I use a datatable (with renderDataTable) I have a column with different combinations of three modalities (e.g., "a", "b", "c", "a|b", "a|b|c"). I would like to implement a filtering option so that when you filter for "a", you would get all combinations with "a" (so "a", "a|b", "a|b|c"). In theory it's very simple (just replacing the filtering condition from == to grepl()) but I did not find any option to do that in DataTable.
Any idea how this can be achieved more or less manually?

Here's a reprex:

```
library(shiny) ; library(dplyr) ; library(plyr) ; library(DT)

data1<-data.frame(ID=1:7, B=as.factor(c("a", "b", "a", "a|b", "a", "c", "a|b|c")))

ui <-fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data1,  filter="top", option=list(search=list(regex=F))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: if you want `B` to be treated as a string, do not wrap it in `as.factor()`. Simply removing that provides the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot langtang! I put the as.factor() originally to set a dropdown menu and did not notice this was preventing from the treating the column as string. But now it's a string there is no dropdown menu. Do you know if I can set one manually (e.g., specifying the dropdown menu should inclue "a", "b", and "c")?